# Sp list item access via c# - clarification

Tags: development, 2007, splistitem, list-item, spcontext

This may be a stupid question but I'm trying to understand what this line of code does. I get that it accesses a list item - but for what List?

```
SPContext.Current.ListItem.Properties["TwitterUsernames"]
```

Could someone shed some light on it for me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would get the data in the column 'TwitterUsernames' for  the current item.